OpenVPN needs lots of connection attempts
I need lots of connection attempts for OpenVPN to connect. It often works after more than five to twenty times. But it works...
Upon failure I receive the following message:
2024-07-30 11:45:58 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED

Upon success I receive the following message:
2024-07-30 11:46:06 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route-gateway ...

Why can I only sometimes connect and how to resolve the issue?
I already made sure with certainty that the following is not the problem:

Wrong credentials.
Account blocking.

This seems to be a Windows-only issue. I use a TCP based connection.

Do you control both ends?  If not, you might want to contact your VPN provider - it may be their authentication metchanisms are not working across all their nodes/devices.

I fully control only one end. The other end is managed in a different department. Thank you for the hint.

Do you use an UDP or TCP based connection to the OpenVPN server?  If it is UDP then the retries may be caused by network problems and thus dropped UDP packets.

I edited the type of connection in the question.
